# How to use jsf "navigation-rule" for direct non .jsf pages ("to-view-id" is not .jsf)

Tags: jsf-2

I want to direct "from-outcome" to some BIRT report file (with .rptdesign extension) but it append extension as .jsf. My navigation rule is,

```
<!-- home.xhtml page -->
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/home.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <!-- navigate to group report -->
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>GROUP_REPORT</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>frameset?__report=report/new_report_group.rptdesign&amp;__overwrite=true&amp;</to-view-id>
        <redirect>
            <view-param>
                <name>Job Location</name>
                <value>#{homeController.jobLocation}</value>
            </view-param>
        </redirect>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Then I got result URL as,
http://192.168.3.111:8080/imc-report-system-1.0/frameset?__report=report%2Fnew_report_group.jsf&Job%20Location=abc
but it should be as, 
http://192.168.3.111:8080/imc-report-system-1.0/frameset?__report=report%2Fnew_report_group.rptdesign&Job%20Location=abc
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know whether that works or not but have tried removing `extension-mapping` in the `web.xml`? Mapping `FacesServlet` to `url-pattern` of `*` instead of `*.jsf`?

Comment: @BheshG, many thanks for the reply, but it is not working with that modification :(. Thanks.

Comment: As a fix I have rewrite the URL with Servlet Filter, but I don't think it is the optimize solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't navigate to a non-JSF-view by a JSF navigation case.

Redirect yourself using [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29).

```
public void submit() {
    // ...

    String url = "frameset"
        + "?__report=report%2Fnew_report_group.rptdesign"
        + "&amp;__overwrite=true"
        + "&amp;Job%20Location=" + jobLocation;

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url);
}
```